# Inequality between norms

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces

Take two integers $d, p \geq 1$ and $a,b,c \in \mathrm{R}_{+}^{d}$ such that $a-b-c \in \mathrm{R}_{+}^{d}$ and $||c||_p \geq ||b||_p$.

Do we have $||a-b||_p \geq ||a-c||_p$ ?

Comment: Consider $a=(2,2)$ and $c=(1,0)$. It is easy to find a value of $b$ that provides a counterexample (at least for $p>1$); try drawing a picture.

Comment: If this is easy can you provide one ?

Comment: Have you tried drawing a picture of the sets $\{b:\|b\|\le\|c\|\}$ and $\{b:\|a-b\|<\|a-c\|\}$? Do they intersect? If so, you have a counterexample.